# SublimeText 3 Build System Error

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, sublimetext

I'm using Sublime Text 3 to write C programs, and I want to set up a build system for my project, so I configured it in the project file as follows:

```
"build_systems":
[
    {
        "name": "GCC+Make",
        "cmd": ["make"],
        "shell": true,
        "working_dir": "${project_path}",
        "variants":
        [
            {
                "name": "Make",
                "cmd": ["make"],
            },
            {
                "name": "Clean",
                "cmd": ["make", "clean"],
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

when I enter `make` in command prompt, every thing works like a charm, but when I built my project using `Ctrl+B` I got the following error, and I'm sure gcc is in %PATH%, does any one know what went wrong?

```
gcc -Wall HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld.exe
make: gcc: Command not found
makefile:4: recipe for target 'HelloWorld.o' failed
make: *** [HelloWorld.o] Error 127
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 2]
[cmd: ['make']]
[dir: D:\userdata\j5shi\OneDrive\Private\Workspace_Jerry\Proj_C\GCC]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Windows\system32;path=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\wbem;C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\program files (x86)\vim\vim74\;c:\python27\;c:\python27\scripts\;c:\totalcmd\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\APPS\svncmdline\bin;c:\apps\Ctags\ctags58\;c:\cygwin\bin;]
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  By "when I enter make in the command prompt..." do you mean the Console in Sublime text or via cmd.exe?

Comment: No, I'm no longer using ST anymore, it's too slow (mainly because of the plugins, which are written in Python), I'm back to VIM again.